# What is the good way to retrieve firmware version on ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm now developing firmware for my board connecting to my ROS linux boxes.
Sometimes I'd like to know which board is connected to the current ROS linux box and what the firmware version is, from ROS node if possible.

I can create my own custom node for publishing the versions but I think ROS should have a node publishing system/device/machine information because they're required for software/firmware update and self-monitoring.

Or is that out of ROS scope? Linux OS should cover it? (therefore, I need to create a systemd service for instance)

Since I'm new to ROS, any good alternate ideas are welcome.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240566/what-is-the-good-way-to-retrieve-firmware-version-on-ros?/) by [dbaba](https://answers.ros.org/users/26800/dbaba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a general ROS node that does this. It also seems not clearly defined, what exactly this information would contain. Depending who is needing what information this is usually also quite straight-forward with standard tools (if not required by some node in the ROS system)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbaba](https://answers.ros.org/users/26800/dbaba/) on 2016-07-28**:
Thanks! Your comment is very helpful for me.
I'll start from a simple script for now and create a node if necessary.